# How to use tqdm through multi process in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, tqdm

I'm trying to use `tqdm` through multi processes. And the behavior is not as expected. I think the point is that the value of `pbar` doesn't update through the processes. So how to deal with this problem? I have also tried to use `Value` to update `pbar.n` manually, but still failed. It seems `tqdm` doesn't support update value and render manually.

```
def test(lock, pbar):
    for i in range(10000):
        sleep(0.1)
        lock.acquire()
        pbar.update()
        lock.release()

pbar = tqdm(total = 10000)
lock = Lock()
for i in range(5):
    Process(target = test, args = (lock, pbar))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, each process has its own data, independent of every other process.
Spawning a new process (which calls `os.fork` on Unix) creates a copy of the
current process. Each process obtains its own copy of all global values (such as
`pbar`).  Each process's global variables may share the same names as variables
in the other processes, but each can hold an independent value.

In your case it looks like you want just one `pbar` to exist, and all calls to
`update` should update that one `pbar`. So create `pbar` in only one process,
and use a `Queue` to send signals to that process to update `pbar`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

SENTINEL = 1

def test(q):
    for i in range(10000):
        sleep(0.1)
        q.put(SENTINEL)

def listener(q):
    pbar = tqdm(total = 10000)
    for item in iter(q.get, None):
        pbar.update()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = mp.Queue()
    proc = mp.Process(target=listener, args=(q,))
    proc.start()
    workers = [mp.Process(target=test, args=(q,)) for i in range(5)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    for worker in workers:
        worker.join()
    q.put(None)
    proc.join()
```

Comment: It works well except block forever at `proc.join()`. I think it could be solved by adding `q.put(None)` before `proc.join()` to finish the listener process. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sraw: Oops, you are quite right. Thanks for the correction.